# How to get the id of the dropped element in jQuery with the draggable method

Tags: jquery

I have to create a drag and drop solution.

I have many elements droppable and to no create bugs (IE8) I want to use the draggable methode.
My question:

How I can retrieve the dropped ID element with my code?

```
$('div[id^="c_"]').draggable({
        containment: '#css_tableau',
        start: function() {
                $('#conteneurPopup').html('');
        },
        drag: function() {
        },
        stop: function(){
             // how I can get the dropped id element ?
        }
});



<table id="css_tableau">
   <tr>
     <td id="td_564556">
          <div id="c_23324"> Project XXX</div>
     </td>
     <td id="td_556596"></td>
     <td id="td_511546"></td>
     <td id="td_564556"></td>
     <td id="td_564756"></td>
     <td id="td_565556"></td>
     <td id="td_564536"></td>
     <td id="td_52556"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

PS: I can not use the "droppable" method.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: I think you'll have to do it in `droppable` not in `draggable`.

Comment: The problem is when I use droppable method the page load 15/20 second...

Answer (score 1):

```
 stop: function(event, ui){
            var draggedID = ui.draggable.attr('id');
            var droppedID = $(this).attr('id');
        }
```

Works for other [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) events.

Comment: Though the question is about `draggable` and not `droppable`.